# Why $\log\mathrm{det}(A (A^{-1}B)^{1/2}) = \log\mathrm{det}(A^{1/2}B^{1/2})$

Tags: matrices

> $A,B$ are positive definite matrices.
>   Show 
>   $$\log\mathrm{det}\left( A^{1/2} (A^{−1/2} B A^{−1/2})^{1/2} A^{1/2} \right) = \log\mathrm{det}(A^{1/2}B^{1/2}) $$

I have known :
$$ A^{1/2} (A^{−1/2} B A^{−1/2})^{1/2} A^{1/2} = A (A^{-1}B)^{1/2} $$
But I can't get 
$$\log\mathrm{det}(A (A^{-1}B)^{1/2}) = \log\mathrm{det}(A^{1/2}B^{1/2})$$
I hope someone will help me. Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't it follow straight from $A(A^{-1}B)^{1/2}=AA^{-1/2}B^{1/2}=A^{1/2}B^{1/2}$ ?

Comment: @J.F, If $A$ and $B$ do not commute, then $(A^{-1}B)^{1/2}$ need not coincide with $A^{-1/2}B^{1/2}$. But their determinants should do.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$ and $\det(A^{1/2}) = \sqrt{\det(A)}$. Use these to pull apart the determinants into products and powers of real numbers, then check if they're equal.

Comment: Than you very much .